# What's at the end of an "await chain"?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I knew "async all the way", but what code should be at the top of an "await chain"?
I knew for WPF event handlers, we use `async void`, and for kestrel, we can simply write `Task<T>` for the return type. So is `async void` or `Task.Wait()` the top for all async codes? (my grammar might be bad, sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on your application. Unless you are forced to write synchronous code at the top (e.g. for legacy reasons), you can really go async all the way. Starting from C# 7.1 you can also have async Main methods. In ASP.NET, controller methods can be async. In unit tests, the test methods can also be async.

Comment: if I write a library like ASP.NET Core, what should I write on the top where I can't do async operations to call these async methods? Just go synchronous? Impl a TaskScheduler/Dispatcher?

Comment: What does "i can't do async" mean? Why can't you do async? Microsoft do async on their libraries all the time (look at EF, e.g. `context.SaveChangesAsync()` - they wrote it asyncly, you call it asyncly). You use their library asyncly, someone uses your lib syncly to write a lib that is async, that someone else uses asyncly.. Async all the way